# pdflatex doesn't allow me to enable system calls from another directory

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-external, shell-escape

I am trying to save the plots in my file into separate PDFs. My file is called `my_file.tex` located in `/full/path/to/my/file`

This is `my_file.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}                                                    
\usepackage{tikz}                                                                
\usetikzlibrary{external}                                                        
\usepackage{pgfplots}                                                            
                                                                                 
\tikzexternalize                                                                 
                                                                                 
\begin{document}                                                                 
\begin{figure}[h]                                                                
    \centering                                                                   
    \begin{tikzpicture}                                                          
        \begin{axis} []                                                          
        \end{axis}                                                               
    \end{tikzpicture}                                                            
\end{figure}                                                                     
\end{document}
```

If I am located in the same directory as `my_file.txt` I can easily get the behaviour I want with:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape my_file
```

The problem is that when I want to compile my document from a different folder, say `/different/path/`, it doesn't work:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape /full/path/to/my/file/my_file
```

I get:

```
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-o
n-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "bvcocc-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalreal
job{bvcocc}\input{bvcocc}"' ========
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256

! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "bvcocc-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob
{bvcocc}\input{bvcocc}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'bvcocc-figure0
' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled 
system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is a
lso named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed
? Error messages can be found in 'bvcocc-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'l
l try to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
```

Comment: as for `\input` the working directory for the system call is whatever is the directory from which you started the pdflatex process, not the directory of the main file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you expand a little bit? I don't understand what you mean, or how to use this information to move forward with my problem. Thanks

Comment: if you are at (say) the root of the filesystem and do `pdflatex /some/long/path/mydirectory/myfile`  then any `\input{abc}` in `myfile` will look for files in the root of the system at `/` not  in `mydirectory` and similarly if you shell escape the command you run will run in `/` (and probably need to have write permissions there) it will not run in `mydirectory`. It is almost always better to do `cd /some/long/path/mydirectory ; pdflatex myfile`  so the working directory is the directory with the document file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There are no inputs in my MWE above, and it fails. Can you replicate the problem I have? Or is it something weird that happens to me/my computer?

Comment: you are using shell-escape which is implemented as an input and as I say has the same feature.  You have not said what is the current directory at the point you run pdflatex. If you use `pdflatex my_file` does it work?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle From the directory with the file `pdflatex my_file` doesn't work; I have to do `pdflatex -shell-escape my_file`. I guess that for the time being I will do `cp /very/long/path/my_file.tex ./; pdflatex -shell-escape my_file; rm my_file.tex` in order to compile my file form anywhere. Do you recommend this as the best I can do?

Comment: or as I say cd to the directory with the file (naturally you need shell-escape in any case) it is almost always a bad idea to use a full path on the commandline. Everything is trickier if you do that, apart from shell-escape, aux files log files etc are not written to the directory with the document and a lot of code assumes that they are written to the directory with the file

Comment: @DanielDuque: Yeah, what David said. I think I struggeled with some similar issues, and eventually decided not to compile from a separate directory. Instead, I do a `cd <dir_where_tex_file_is> ; pdflatex ... ; cd <back_to_original_dir>` (or use `pushd`/`popd`). As it was a while ago, I don't recall the specfic issues, but this may help.  My issues at the time was not with `\tikzexternalize`, so perhaps for that there are other (possibly simpler) options.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** to get the right file names for the figures, like  `myfile-figure0.pdf`.

Initial setup (tree of a windows OS)

[image: b]

and a proper configured `myfile.tex` in its own directory.

```
%%%% file myfile.tex

\documentclass[11pt]{article}                                                    
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[%
up to date check={simple},
prefix=./different/tikzfiles/]% Folder needs to be created before compiling

\tikzset{external/system call={%
        pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
        -halt-on-error -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode -output-directory=./different/ 
        -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}              

\begin{document}                                                                 
    \begin{figure}[h]                                                                
        \centering                                                                   
        \begin{tikzpicture}                                                          
            \begin{axis} []                                                          
            \end{axis}                                                               
        \end{tikzpicture}                                                            
    \end{figure}                                                                     
\end{document}
```

Run from the command prompt of the empty `WorkingDirectory`.
Note the pointing to the output directory with the option `-output-directory=`. All intermediate and final files will go there.

`pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode  -shell-escape -output-directory=./different/   ./different/myfile.tex`

[image: cm2]

To get

[image: af]

Comment: I don't think it works. I didn't get the `my_file-figure0.pdf`, and from your screenshot it seems that you don't get it either.

Comment: @Daniel Duque  You need to have a proper configured `.tex `  file to get that output. Please try my updated answer.